# How do you make a ban/unban/kick command with nextcord?

Tags: python, nextcord

I want to make a ban, kick, and unban command with my discord bot.
I also want it to be compatible with slash commands.
If you need the code, here it currently is.

```
from nextcord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != bot.user:
        print(f'(#{message.channel}) {message.author}: {message.content}')
        
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    print(f'User {message.author} has deleted "{message.content}"')

@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    print(f'User {before.author} has edited "{before.content}" to "{after.content}"')

bot.run('my token')
```

Comment: `I want to make a ban, kick, and unban command with my discord bot. I also want it to be compatible with slash commands` → Okay we permit it. please make. What is actual question? And what you tried to do?

Comment: @rzlvmp the question is how do i add these commands to my code. im trying to add them

Comment: [For example](https://dev.to/mikeywastaken/events-in-discord-py-mk0)

Answer (score 0):

For a kick command you can do:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):
    if user == None:
        await ctx.send("Please enter a user!")
        return

    await user.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Kicked {user.name} for reason {reason}')
```

For a ban command you can do:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):
    if user == None:
        await ctx.send("Please enter a user!")
        return

    await user.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Banned {user.name} for reason {reason}')
```

And for an unban command you can do:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.name}#{user.discriminator}')
```

I'm not really sure how to do / commands but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

just change @bot.command() to @bot.slash_command() for slash command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).